# Docker Volume overwriting file permissions

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile where I bring in some files and change permissions. 
I also have a docker-compose that creates a volume for nodemon to watch. I believe that these volumes are overwriting the permissions that I set. When I remove the volumes the app works but I don't get the server restarting. When the volumes are there the app crashes due to permissions. I've tried creating the volume first but perhaps I was doing that wrong.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl sudo
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs && \
apt-get install --yes build-essential
RUN apt-get install --yes npm

#VOLUME "/usr/local/app"

# Set up C++ dev env
RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
   apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib cmake wget -y  && \
   apt-get clean autoclean && \
   apt-get autoremove -y
   #wget -O /tmp/conan.deb -L https://github.com/conan-io/conan/releases/download/0.25.1/conan-ubuntu-64_0_25_1.deb && \
   #dpkg -i /tmp/conan.deb

#ADD ./scripts/cmake-build.sh /build.sh
#RUN chmod +x /build.sh
#RUN /build.sh


RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs sudo


RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/app
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY package.json /usr/local/app
RUN ["npm", "install"]
RUN npm install --global nodemon
COPY . .


RUN echo "/usr/local/app/dm" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN echo "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN echo "/usr/local/lib64" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN ldconfig

EXPOSE 9090
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "dm/dm3"]
RUN ["chmod", "777", "policy"]
RUN ls -al .
RUN npm -v
RUN node -v
```

notice at the end where i'm changing permissions.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/local/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    command: nodemon
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: docker volume works that the host mounts its folder to docker container. If the folder is empty and your container folder is full of files the container will have empty folder too because the volume overwrites it...

Comment: Please post the file permission error messages. This issue may come from multiple sources. One is what Constantin mentioned in his answer and that answer may solve your issue. Another reason for having such problems may lie in file ownership differences between host and the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mount volumes into a docker container,  the files inside are on a lower layer so they are hidden.

In your case,  `/usr/local/app` from the Dockerfile is hidden. Its contents are the files from the host machine (the parent directory of `docker-compose.yml`). You should set the permissions in the host machine.